# Accidental early return statement

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have trying to make a responsive navbar in React using Material UI but this code crashes when the window sizes reduces below 900px giving the error **Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.**  The error is in the useEffect hook. But I just can't figure out why this giving me a error. I am guessing it is because of violation of a hook rule. But I have tried everything but I am still not able to fix it.

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import {AppBar ,Toolbar, Container ,makeStyles,Button, IconButton ,Drawer} from '@material-ui/core'
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'

const usestyles = makeStyles({
  root:{
    display:'flex',
    justifyContent:'space-between' ,
    maxWidth:'700px'
  },
  menubtn:{
    fontFamily: "Work Sans, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 500,
    paddingRight:'79px',
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "left",
  },
  menuicon:{
    edge: "start",color: "inherit",paddingLeft:'0'
  }
})

const menudata = [
  {
    label: "home",
    href: "/",
  },
  {
    label: "About",
    href: "/about",
  },
  {
    label: "Skill",
    href: "/skills",
  },
  {
    label: "Projects",
    href: "/projects",
  },
  {
    label: "Contact",
    href: "/contact",
  },
];


function Navbar() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({mobileview:false,draweropen:false});
  const {mobileview,draweropen} = state;
  const {menuicon,root} =usestyles();


  function getmenubuttons(){
    const {menubtn} = usestyles();
    return menudata.map(({label,href})=>{
      return <Button className={menubtn}>{label}</Button>
    })
  }


  function displaydesktop(){

    return <Toolbar >
      <Container maxWidth={false} className={root}>
        {getmenubuttons()}
      </Container>
    </Toolbar>
  }

  function displaymobile(){

    return <Toolbar>
      <IconButton className={menuicon} >
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>

    </Toolbar>
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const setResponsiveness = () => {
      return window.innerWidth < 900
        ? setState((state)=>({ ...state, mobileview: true }))
        : setState((state)=>({ ...state, mobileview: false }));
    };

    setResponsiveness();

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar> {mobileview? displaymobile() :displaydesktop() } </AppBar>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usestyles` is a hook and you call it twice for desktop but only once for mobile as mobile doesn't use menu buttons. To solve this problem you can create a separate component for menu and add it to the desktop view. This component will be calling `usestyles` inside itself, thus the parent will have the same number of hooks on each render.

So you transform

```
function getmenubuttons(){
  const {menubtn} = usestyles();
  return menudata.map(({label,href})=>{
    return <Button className={menubtn}>{label}</Button>
  })
}
```

into

```
function MenuButtons({menudata}){
  const {menubtn} = usestyles();

    return (<>
     {menudata.map(({label,href})=>  <Button className={menubtn}>{label}</Button>)}
     </>)
}
```

Comment: hey your fix worked but I m still a bit confused regarding the cause of the error ,like the error was because useStyles() hook was being called inside condition but by making the menubuttons(parent of the hook) a component we can use hook inside conditions as well? I am a beginner to hooks so it would really helpful if you can explain this a bit more

Comment: That's correct, hooks are associated with their components, you need to have the same number of hooks per component, but its child-components and their hooks don't count.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setState` invoked within `useEffect` without any dependencies nor conditions will lead to an infinite loop of re-renders.